# numpy vectorized operations slower than looping + vectorization?

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, numpy-ndarray

- I have a 3 dimensional numpy array of shape 20X10_000X15 and I would like to multiply it against a 1 dimensional numpy array of shape 1X15.
- I would expect that the fastest way to do this is to use numpy vectorized methods and avoid for loops altogether.
- In practice it seems that a hybrid approach of using a small amount of looping is faster than the purely vectorized operation.
- For example:

  ```
  N = 10_000
  # Purely vectorized method: Multiply 20XNX15 array against a 1X15 array
  a = np.random.rand(20, N, 15)
  b = np.random.rand(15)
  %timeit np.multiply(b, a)

  # Multiply NX15 array against a 1X15 array 20 times
  a = np.random.rand(N, 15)
  b = np.random.rand(15)

  %timeit for i in range(20): np.multiply(b, a)

  >>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>
  7.93 ms ± 57.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
  5.43 ms ± 223 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
  ```
- The trend persists until I decrease the array size to below 20X3000X15, at which point the vectorized approach is faster
- Does anyone know the reason for this? Does numpy have a diminishing return on vectorized operations on large arrays?
- Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: TIL that `_` is a valid syntax in numbers.